# Can't knit a markdown that uses arcgisbinding package in R

Tags: arcgis-pro, markdown

I am working in R with the arcgisbinding package. All of my code executes seamlessly. But when I try to knit the document I get this error:

> *Quitting from lines 34-77 (reanalysis.Rmd)
> Error in eval(parse_only(code), envir = envir) :
> object 'parcels_wSaltMarsh' not found
> Calls:  ... inline_exec -> hook_eval -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
> Execution halted*

This is my code.

```
library(arcgisbinding)
arc.check_product()
gdb <- "path/geodatabase.gdb"
parcels.marsh <- arc.open(paste(gdb, sep="", "parcels_wSaltMarsh") )
```

The working directory is set appropriately, and all the associated file are together in the working directory. Again: code runs fine, but when I try to knit the markdown file I run into trouble.

Comment: It seems to be not finding an R object called `parcels_wSaltMarsh`, which is strange because you don't mention an object with that name in your code, you have it as the name of the gdb layer you are trying to load. Can you open other layers? Can you triple check that `file.exists(gdb)` is TRUE when rendering?

Comment: Within the R environment, I can open all of my layers and I can write layers back to the geodatabase. `file.exists(gdb)` came back TRUE.